# Change fade to slide

Tags: jquery

How can I change the fade to slide left/right?

```
 changeList = function () {

            listItems.eq(i).fadeOut(transition_speed, function () {
                i += 1;
                if (i === listLen) {
                    i = 0;
                }
                listItems.eq(i).fadeIn(transition_speed);
            });

        };
```

I've found a code; however, don't know how to implement because the first part (fade out) has a function attached.

`.show( "slide", {direction: "left" }, 2000 );`

and then

`.hide( "slide", {direction: "left" }, 2000 );`

is that the best way to achieve this, or is there a better way?

------EDIT------

```
        changeList = function () {

            listItems.eq(i).hide({
    easing : "slide",
    direction: "left",
    duration : 2000,
    complete: function(){
        i += 1;
                if (i === listLen) {
                    i = 0;
                }
                listItems.eq(i).show({
    easing : "slide",
    direction: "left",
    duration : 2000 });
    }
            });
};
```

This edit didn't work.  I probably implemented it wrong

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use this toggling effect

```
$("#left_panel").toggle("slide", { direction: "left" }, 1000);
```

i have edited.

```
$('a.view-list-item').click(function () {
    var divname= this.name;
    $("#"+divname).show("slide", { direction: "left" }, 1000);
    $("#"+divname).parent().siblings(":visible").hide("slide", { direction: "left" }, 1000);
});
```

Comment: can you show me how that would look inside the code?  My issue is not knowing how to implement this piece of code inside existing code....

Comment: what is you exact requirement bro?

Comment: this conditions are for what purpose ?i += 1;
                if (i === listLen) {
                    i = 0;
                }

Comment: basically to where it looks like the new graphic slides on top of the old graphic.  Thats it.  Its inside a slider (banner on website)

Comment: would be best if next graphic slides in, and then old graphic gets hidden.  I dunno.  Just want it to look nice.

Comment: I looked at your jsfiddle and it doesn't work in there and it isn't working on my site either....hmm

Answer (score 1):

You can do it without jQuery UI.

use `.animate({ width: property }, 2000);`

**property**:

- 0 - to hide
- 200px - to show with size 200px
- 'toggle' - to toggle

Reference: [jQuery API Animate](https://api.jquery.com/animate/)

Comment: how would I plug that into my code?  I've never done this before

Comment: listItems.eq(i).animate({ width: property }, 2000);